# locating a text file Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

I am trying to get path of legal.txt in my project. However, whatever I do. I am getting a null path back. it is in the Policies directory. How do I get it's path as a string. I need to send that path to a webview controller. Can someone help.

```
-(void)linkPressedOnTextView:(PPLinksTextView *)tv url:(NSURL *)url{


    if ([url.host isEqualToString:@"sign_up"]) {
        GetStartedController *getStartedVC = [[GetStartedController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:getStartedVC animated:YES];

    }

    else if([url.host isEqualToString:@"consentMedicalSevices"]){

        PPNavigationViewController *vc = [[PPNavigationViewController alloc]init];
        [vc openPolicies:@"Policies/privacy.txt"];
```

Will this work. I need a way to direct user to a webview once he clicks on the link and privacy text opens up.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. And be sure the text files are being copied to your app's resource bundle.

Comment: Where do I drop these files then? which folder?

Comment: Assets folder available in the project

Comment: what code did you tried man?

Comment: tried adding throug NSBundle mainBundle.

Comment: There is no assets folder in my project just image.xcassets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From apple doc:*

```
pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:
```

***Returns the full pathname for the resource file identified by the specified name and extension and residing in a given bundle directory.***

```
NSString *filePath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    NSLog(@"File Path:  %@", filePath);
```

**Output:**

```
File Path:  /Users/Ashok/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F629F99F-C745-46EB-8A11-01BC9FF1E592/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EB4EA25F-65E6-4CA8-B8C2-C7C0C64C6C0F/Sample.app/file.txt
```